# How to make multiple database relation criteria in yii php framework?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have two databases tv_schedule and vp_record.
In vp_record table setted relation:

```
    'tv_schedule' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Schedule', 'sch_id'),
```

When i'm trying to get related record, it's working for me fine:

```
    Record::model()->findByPk(2)->tv_schedule
```

But when i'm using **criteria** for forming dataProvider, i have error:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'video_processing.tv_schedule' doesn't exist. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `video_processing`.`vp_record` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tv_schedule` `tv_schedule` ON (`t`.`sch_id`=`tv_schedule`.`sch_id`) WHERE (t.tc_id = 22)

```
     $dataProviderRecorded = new CActiveDataProvider('Record', array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'with' => array('tv_schedule'),
            'condition' => 't.tc_id = '.$id,
            'together' => true
        ),
        'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => 20
        )
    ));
```

But in model of record, and in model of schedule configured method CDbGetConnection:

```
 public function getDbConnection()
{
    $db = Yii::app()->getComponent('video_processing');

    if ($db instanceof CDbConnection)
    {
        return $db;
    }
    else
        throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii', 'Active Record requires a "video_processing" CDbConnection application component.'));
}
```

Schedule:

```
    public function getDbConnection() 
    {
            $db=Yii::app()->getComponent('iptv_new');

            if($db instanceof CDbConnection)
            {
                    return $db;
            }
            else 
                    throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','Active Record requires a "iptv_new" CDbConnection application component.'));
    }
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: This is not supported, because Yii will try a `JOIN` query whenever possible. You can't join accross different databases.

Comment: but query with two and more databases in yii working... `video_processing`.`vp_record`,  `iptv_new`.`schedule`. But i need to get database name from CDbConnection class for making direct sql query...

Comment: i'm not found in api that too... When i specify full tablename all is working..